# I'm not sure what these error messages means

Tags: c++

> error:>In file included from 244_w5_lab_prof.cpp:11:0:
>   Fraction.h: In member function ‘sict::Fraction& sict::Fraction::operator*?>>>(sict::Fraction) const’:
>   Fraction.h:83:13: warning: reference to local variable ‘bb’ returned [enabled by default]
>   Fraction.h: In member function ‘sict::Fraction sict::Fraction::operator+(sict::Fraction)’:
>   Fraction.h:78:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
>   In file included from Fraction.cpp:12:0:
>   Fraction.h: In member function ‘sict::Fraction& sict::Fraction::operator*>(sict::Fraction) const’:
>   Fraction.h:83:13: warning: reference to local variable ‘bb’ returned [enabled by 
>   default]

```
    #ifndef SICT_Fraction_H__
    #define SICT_Fraction_H__

    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    namespace sict{

       class Fraction{
       private:

        int num;                // Numerator
        int denom;              // Denominator

        int gcd();            // returns the greatest common divisor of num 
         and denom


  int max();        // returns the maximum of num and denom
  int min();        // returns the minimum of num and denom

        public:

    void reduce();     // simplifies a Fraction number by dividing the 
                       // numerator and denominator to their greatest common  
    divisor 

    Fraction();                             // default constructor
    Fraction(int n , int d=1);               // construct n/d as a Fraction 
    number

    void display() const {
        if (num < 0 || denom < -1)
            cout << "Invalid Fraction Object!";
        else if (denom == 1)
            cout << num;
        else {

            cout<<num<<"/"<< denom;
        } 
    }

    bool isEmpty() const;     

    // member operator functions

    // TODO: write the prototype of member operator+= function HERE
    Fraction & operator+=(const Fraction & f) {
        num = num*f.denom + denom*f.num;
        denom = denom*f.denom;
        reduce();
        return *this;

    }

    // TODO: write the prototype of member operator+ function HERE
    Fraction operator+(const Fraction & f) {
        if (!(this->denom == -1 || f.denom == -1))
        {
            Fraction temp;
            temp.num = num*f.denom + denom*f.num;
            temp.denom = denom*f.denom;
            temp.reduce();


            return temp;
        }

    }


    // TODO: write the prototype of member operator* function HERE
    Fraction & operator*(const Fraction & f) const {
        Fraction temp;
        temp.num = num*f.num;
        temp.denom = denom*f.denom;
        temp.reduce();

                return temp;
            }
       };
    };
    #endif
```

Comment: One thing they mean is that this is not the code that produced those error messages, since the messages refer to names that are not in this code.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`SICT_Fraction_H__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: The warning message means that the named function returns a reference to a destroyed variable. Don't do that. You don't know what you will get.

Answer (score 1):

`operator+` only returns something when the if-statement is true. It has to *always* return something.

The `operator*`, on the other hand, returns a reference to the local variable `temp`. It should likely also return by value, like `operator+`.

Comment: huh?I don't quite get it. What should I do?

Comment: @Zanonymous What, _exactly_ don't you understand?

Comment: @Zanonymous That depends, on the logic you want to implement. Based on information posted, all we can do is, to explain what they mean. It's up to you to act on this information.